# How to create line in the center on scroll with circle in SVG and how to decrease the speed of drawing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

For creating a `circle` on `page scroll` with `line` I am doing like this:

```js
var createShape = document.getElementById("shape");
var length = createShape.getTotalLength();
shape.style.strokeDasharray = length;
shape.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
window.onscroll = function myFunction() {
  var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop) /
      ( document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
       document.documentElement.clientHeight );
  var draw = length * scrollpercent;
  shape.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw ;
}
```

```css
.scroll_text {
  font-family: "arial";
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(241, 71, 71, 1);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="scroll_text">Please  Scroll</p>
<svg id="mySVG" width="1500px" height="1500px">
  <path d="M 500, 500
           m 20, -190
           a 20,20 0 1,0 1,0
           Q 520 800, 520 800
           a 20,20 0 1,0 1,0
           Q 520 1200, 520 1200
           a 20,20 0 1,0 1,0
           Q 520 1500, 520 1500"
        fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2px" id="shape"/>           
</svg>
```

But the problem is my line is intersecting the circle. So, for this i want to fill my circle when my circle finishes up. but for this if I give "fill" then it shows colour. What should I do? I am new to SVG. Is there anyone how can help me out?

Here is the link:
http://codepen.io/VishakhaNehe/pen/ezBoGW

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have a problem with the circle creation? Or the problem is that the circle gets scrolled up and you want it to be fixed on screen when scrolling?

Comment: I am creating a circle on scroll then when it finishes up a straight line gets start from there to some distance then again a circle gets started. I am trying to do it in SVG but I am unable to understand how to create that line in centre and again that circle.

Comment: Should I use more than one svg tag to create them one after another?

Comment: @vish please use jsfiddle.com to demonstrate the problem (include the saved link in the question). Also, you should state a clear problem+question in the content.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Please have a look..